# Using PHP mail() function twice in a row is causing second use to be missing content

Tags: php, email

Problem: The sendEmail() function in the second ob_start works EXCEPT that the $emailContents are not being received in the Email.

NOTES:

- The first email is sent containing everything as expected.
- The second email is also sent with the subject but no contents
- If I take the second instance and test it by itself, the email is sent containing everything as expected.
- The file paths are correct and the files are where they are supposed to be.

I know you may need to see more, but from my perspective the following code are the only parts involved that could possibly contain the cause of the problem, but let me know if there's something else you need to see to help me.

```
function sendEmail($mailTo, $emailSubject, $emailContents)
{
  $headers = "From: registrations@" . DOMAIN . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: registrations@" . DOMAIN . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Return-Path: registrations@" . DOMAIN . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version:1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  mail($mailTo, $emailSubject, $emailContents, $headers);
}
```

The above function and the problem area are in two separate files:

```
ob_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../Emails/registration.php';
$emailContents = ob_get_clean();
sendEmail($user['email'], 'Account Registration at ' . FULL_SITE_NAME, $emailContents);

ob_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../Emails/registrationAlert.php';
$emailContents = ob_get_clean();
sendEmail(ALERT_EMAIL, 'Registration by ' . $user['firstName'] . ' ' . $user['lastName'], $emailContents);
```

The following is the /Emails/registrationAlert.php but it works when by itself, exactly as expected! It is ONLY when the two emails are being sent side by side like shown above that the second ones contents are missing.

```
ob_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Sections/logoHeader.php';
?>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:30px;background-color:#ffffff;">
                <h1 style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:16px;font-size:26px;line-height:32px;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:-0.02em;">New Registered Member!</h1>
                  <h2 style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:16px;font-size:18px;line-height:32px;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:-0.02em;"><?=$user['firstName'] . ' ' . $user['lastName']?> Registration</h2>
                <p style="margin:0;"><?=$user['firstName'] . ' ' . $user['lastName']?> has registered using <?=$user['email']?></p>
              </td>
            </tr>
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/Sections/regularFooter.php';

$thisEmailContents = ob_get_clean();

require_once __DIR__ . '/emailTemplate.php'
```

What am I missing? I've even changed the second $emailContents var to $emailContents2 out of desperation, and oddly then the email subject header was missing. Even some hints as to where you would look for problems if you can't see clearly what I've done wrong would be helpful.

Is there a timing issue with mail? I've used mail to submit dozens of emails back to back in loops, maybe the loop provides enough time for the previous email to complete? I don't know, I'm literally just guessing at this point.

Comment: `registrationAlert.php` is doing 
`$thisEmailContents = ob_get_clean();`. This clears the output buffer, so there's nothing for `$emailContents = ob_get_clean();` to get.

Comment: Ok, I looked into nesting Ob_start and thought I understood it, but clearly I don't. How would I then keep using ob_start in the nested includes?

Comment: You can nest output buffers, but they don't accumulate. The buffer in the main script will containing everything that was output outside the nested `ob_start/ob_get_clean()`. Which is nothing.

Comment: Another possible problem. If `logoHeader.php` is required in both `registration.php` and `registrationAlert.php`, it will be skipped in the second because of `require_once`.

Comment: This whole design seems poorly conceived. Include files should define functions that you can call to get the output, rather than producing the output directly and using output buffering to capture it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, if you don't mind educating me, what would be the proper way of constructing the email contents? I'm trying to reduce repeated code by constructing many different automated emails from template pieces.

Comment: `function registrationAlert($user) { return  ... }`. You can use a here-string in the `return` statemeent to substitute elements of the `$user` array.

Comment: After changing the require_once to "require" in each case, everything is now working as I expected. Somehow the output buffering is working, at least to get the results I was expecting from it. But catching my amateur mistake of using the wrong type of include fixed my problem! Thanks again, and if you do have a suggestion for a better way to construct emails from template pieces, I'm always willing to learn!